# Docker Compose and Rails: Bundler::GemNotFound upon launching. Is bundler not looking at the right gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundler

I'm trying to follow the instructions to setup a Rails and Postgres app with Docker Compose as stated on the documentation here -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/.

However, when I try to launch the app, after having successfully setup the database, I'm stuck with the following error upon running `docker-compose up`:

```
docker-compose up
Creating docker-and-cms_db_1 ... done
Creating docker-and-cms_web_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-and-cms_db_1, docker-and-cms_web_1
web_1  | bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)
web_1  | Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find bindex-0.8.1 in any of the sources
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
docker-and-cms_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Some early investigations on my end:

- I'm using the ruby:2.6.5 image, and the error message seems to indicate that bundler is trying to look for gems in the `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0` folder and that does look suspicious. I suspect an issue of version, maybe an environment not properly set.

Here is my **`Dockerfile`**

```
# From https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/
FROM ruby:2.6.5

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install --path vendor/cache

COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Here is my **`entrypoind.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

And finally here is my **`docker-compose.yml`** file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And here is the beginning of my **`Gemfile`** (redacted, because only the first lines are relevant I think):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4', '>= 5.2.4.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# (...)
```

Debug information:
- This is what running `bundle env` in the docker container returns:

```
root@588227887e16:/myapp# bundle env
## Environment


Bundler       1.17.2
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /usr/local/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /usr/local/etc
RubyGems      3.0.3
  Gem Home    /usr/local/bundle
  Gem Path    /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/bundle
  User Path   /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  Bin Dir     /usr/local/bundle/bin
Tools
  Git         2.20.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed


## Bundler Build Metadata


Built At          2018-12-19
Git SHA           3fc4de72b
Released Version  false


## Bundler settings


path
  Set for your local app (/usr/local/bundle/config): "vendor/cache"
app_config
  Set via BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG: "/usr/local/bundle"
silence_root_warning
  Set via BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING: true
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Got odl Rails containers running long time ago, it's a environment issues. have a look to this (very old) https://github.com/noxsnono/Docker/blob/master/ruby232_sql_rails/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

Within the Docker container Bundler is looking for gems in the wrong directory as you say. Either Ruby 2.6.0 is installed and found by Bundler when the container is starting or, something is copied into the container to make Bundler believe Ruby 2.6.0 is installed.

As you're using the Docker image ruby:2.5.6, the second option above is more likely

If you look on lines 8-9 of your Dockerfile you'll see that the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are copied from your local machine into the container, when building the Docker image.

I think what may be happening here is that the Gemfile.lock generated on your local machine was done using Ruby 2.6.0.

What is your local machine (not in a container) Ruby version? Run `ruby -v` to see.

Try installing Ruby 2.6.5 on your local machine and running `bundle install`, to update the Gemfile.lock.

I'm on my mobile, can't test any of this myself currently. But it's somewhere to start!

Comment: Thank you for your help! The ruby version on my local machine is ruby 2.6.3p62 . Not that I was previously using rvm on my local machine to manage my Ruby versions. Since it's an empty project so far, I'll try removing my Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Note that the Gemfile.lock seems to have been generated with ruby 2.6.5 though (copying the end of the file here). 

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2

Comment: I edited the question, adding, the bundle env result from the container.